# Close all postman tabs before startup

Tags: postman

I really don't know if this is the right place to ask.
The last time I used `postman`, I had a tab open with a really really long response body, or maybe it was the request body, or perhaps the url?
Anyway, `postman` wasn't responding, so I killed it with task manager.

Today I open postman and it tries to load my open tabs - including the tab with a very long body. As a result, `postman` hangs and I have to kill it.

Is there a cache file I can delete somewhere to make postman open without the tabs? Or a command-line option?

Comment: In your %appData%/Postman you can find same cache and config file, really don't know but i think one of that store last tabs open. I suggest to copy files before delete them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same thing just happened to me. I found a "window" file within Library/Application Support/Postman (Mac). Opened it using VI and removed all the entries, saved and started postman. All my tabs were closed and collections were retained.

Comment: On my windows 7, I found this file in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Postman. Clearing it resolves the problem.

Comment: On linux the window file is in ~/.config/Postman directory

Comment: It's the Library directory under ~ and not under / in mac os

Answer (score 3):

You can right-click on any tab and select Close all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to delete the cache files or delete Postman folder itself, it can be found in Windows here:

```
 C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Postman 
 C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Postman
```