# Postman Not Loading Tabs and Can't Close Them

Tags: postman

I have 4 tabs that postman keeps trying to load, but cannot. I've tried force-closing these tabs as well with no success. Anyone have any idea what the issue could be and how to fix it? I've already uninstalled-reinstalled and that doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: I also have the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can try to press Force close all tabs and then close, reopen the postman. I don't know reason but it work for me :)

Comment: Yeah tried that, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Its already answered in this thread
[Close all postman tabs before startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668547/close-all-postman-tabs-before-startup)

Location for the window File in Mac

```
cat ~/Library/Application Support/Postman/window
```